# Grafana / prometheus: understand rate function

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Using Grafana to graph a simple timeline from prometheus:

[image]

Why there is a such difference between `rate` and `avg` function?

`rate` give point less then minimum value

Answer (score 0):

`rate()` is function to specify the time window for the quantile calculation.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile

Answer (score -1):

`rate()` calculates the amount of events per second (from a counter, that is incemented for every single event)

`avg()` is an aggregation operator to calculate one timeline out of multiple.

They are completely different functionalities.

Comment: So rate dont care about values?

Comment: I dont understand your question, rate calculates the increase of a counter (ignoring the resets) for a specific time and ther transforming that to event/s.

Comment: you said "the amount of events per second" , I understand how many events per second right?

Comment: maybe have a look into the documentation.